# prevent generating new jsessionid?

Tags: spring-security

greetings all
my application uses spring framework,spring security 3.0.2
we use apache tomcat as app server
the problem is that with each new request to the application
a new jsessionid is generated and a new session is created so the user is logged out
and that's weird,why generating new jsessionid,how to stop that? 
i reviewed the code,nothing is creating a new session?
is it a framework problem or app server problem or what?
your help is very appreciated.
thank you.

Comment: Can you post your configuration xml file(s)?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're browser does not receive a valid JSESSIONID cookie (or is blocking it). You can check this by using Firefox with the webdeveloper plugin and check the cookies->view cookies information.

This can be caused by several things, for example:
- you servlet server is behind a proxy and does not run on the same domain as you're website and thus creates cookies for a wrong domain (that thus are ignored by you're browser)
- you're cookie path is incorrect and thus not available to the rest of the application.